# Something confused about the sequence diagram

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

I'm new to the sequence diagram. I'm confused in the rules of the return message. For example, the line of displaySupplierRecord() should be **dotted line or solid line**? And also the **arrow of the line** should be **<** or should be like the **black arrow of the line in getSupplierRecord()**? Last question is usually **does we return data to the actor**?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A **solid line** denotes a request message (i.e. a call initiated by a sender), a **dashed line** denotes a response message (i.e. the answer to a call).

A **solid arrowhead** denotes a synchronous message (i.e. the sender must wait for the response), a **lined arrowhead** denotes an asynchronous message (i.e. the sender can continue without waiting for the response).

In your case, *displaySupplierRecord()* seems to be a function call to the *ProcurementUI* component, so it should be a solid line. *getSupplierRecord()* could be either synchronous (if *ProcurementControl* must wait for the operation to complete before going on) or asynchronous (if there is no waiting).

Your use case also requires the system to send a response back to the actor, so I would recommend to show this in the sequence diagram (as you already did).

Here are two sources for further reading on UML sequence diagrams:

- [UML Sequence Diagram Tutorial](https://www.lucidchart.com/pages/uml-sequence-diagram)
- [UML 2 Tutorial - Sequence Diagram](https://sparxsystems.com/resources/tutorials/uml2/sequence-diagram.html)